# Insert width & height attributes to all images displayed on each page

Tags: functions, images

Using the WordPress `the_content` tag, I am running a custom function to search for all images that do not have a `width` and `height` attribute set and insert the proper dimensions. Below is the function:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_img_dimensions' );

function add_img_dimensions( $image_no_dimensions ) { // Insert width & height to images missing dimensions
    if ( preg_match_all( '/<img [^>]+width=[^>]+height=>/i', $image_no_dimensions, $result ) ) {
        // Do nothing...
    }
    else {
        preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src)=("[^"]*")/i', $image_no_dimensions, $img );
        list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) ) );
        $imgname = str_replace( "\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) );
    }

    return sprintf( '<img src="%s" width="%dpx" height="%dpx" />', str_replace("\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) ), $width, $height );
}
```

For example, if there is an image on one of my pages that looks like the following:

```
<img src="https://link.to/sum/img.jpg" alt="Image Title" />
```

It will then insert the `width` and `height` of the actual image:

```
<img width="150" height="50" src="https://link.to/sum/img.jpg" alt="Image Title" />
```

The function works as expected. However, all of the page's content is replace with the first image that it finds that don't have dimensions set.

How can I `return` all of the content but only change the images that don't have a dimension?

**Before and after**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested and confirmed that this works:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_dimensions' );

function add_image_dimensions( $content ) {

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);

    if (count($images) < 1)
        return $content;

    foreach ($images[0] as $image) {
        preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|class|id|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image, $img );

        if ( !in_array( 'src', $img[1] ) )
            continue;

        if ( !in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || !in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
            $src = $img[2][ array_search('src', $img[1]) ];
            $alt = in_array( 'alt', $img[1] ) ? ' alt=' . $img[2][ array_search('alt', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $title = in_array( 'title', $img[1] ) ? ' title=' . $img[2][ array_search('title', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $class = in_array( 'class', $img[1] ) ? ' class=' . $img[2][ array_search('class', $img[1]) ] : '';
            $id = in_array( 'id', $img[1] ) ? ' id=' . $img[2][ array_search('id', $img[1]) ] : '';
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( str_replace( "\"", "" , $src ) );

            $image_tag = sprintf( '<img src=%s%s%s%s%s width="%d" height="%d" />', $src, $alt, $title, $class, $id, $width, $height );
            $content = str_replace($image, $image_tag, $content);
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: It works, excellent! However, I notice the `class` is stripped form my sample images. Is there a way to retain all of the tags besides the class? If you could show me where to do that, I can try it myself.

Comment: Updated the code so it will add `class` and `id` attributes.

Comment: Great, thank you. I see where you add the extra tags for the image. One more question: I notice that my sample items have `title=""` and `id=""` set like that because they were not originally included in the image. Is there a way to only display the tags that have information in it? In this instance, it won't show the `title` and `id` since nothing was originally set.

Comment: Updated the code again. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @NateAllen, this doesn't work with `srcset` and when `data-src` is used.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to return the full content when using `the_content` filter. But the code you have will not quite handle multiple images anyway... something like this might do it better, by extracting all the image tags first then looping to maybe add the width/height to each and replacing the original tag:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_img_dimensions' );

function add_img_dimensions( $content ) { 

    preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images);
    if (count($images) < 1) {return $content;}

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        preg_match_all( '/(alt|title|src|width|height)=("[^"]*")/i', $image[0], $img );
        // Insert width & height to image if no width specified
        if (!isset($img[3])) {
            $imgalt = str_replace( "\"", "" , ( $img[0][0] ) );                                 
            $imgtitle = str_replace( "\"", "" , ( $img[1][0] ) );
            $imgname = str_replace( "\"", "" , ( $img[2][0] ) );                
            list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $imgname );
            $newimagetag = sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" title="%s" width="%dpx" height="%dpx" />', $imgname, $imgalt, $imgtitle, $width, $height );
            $content = str_replace($image, $newimagetag, $content);
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Note: Untested I'm not sure I have the index references just right... also you will lose any inline styles or other attributes (eg. border) this way so further would need to be done to preserve those.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this question.

I tried out the code and I get an error `preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given` which is referring to line 9 of your code. From doing some research, it looks like there is an issue with it being an array. I've seen a suggestion to use `preg_grep`.

Also another error: `getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty`. May you help go through your code so I can understand it?

Comment: hmmm yeah like I said some indexes may be off, I have edited and changed `$image` to `$image[0]` on that line see if that fixes it... `$image` is basically the full HTML tag match there eg. `<img src="http://someurl.com">` ... you can always `print_r($image);` on the line before if that doesn't work it should help debug the index.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like that fixed it, but another issue shows up:  `Undefined offset: 3` for line 11 and `str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given` for line 17. If it helps, I've set up the following sample content to test out your function: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/factmaven/5c457ffae2a96d0a7d89d21a58387f11)

Comment: yeah whoops the third parameter should be `$content` and changed the check on the image array... let me know if that fixes it and if not I'll check out the gist.

Comment: Progress! Thanks for the update. However, [it looks like all of the image are not replaced with just one](https://i.imgur.com/Lh8Fyfy.gif)